# How to restrict input values and save it separately jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a jquery beginner working on a input as shown in the picture where the user has to follow proper syntax like "name=value". I want to make validations if the entered data is in the correct format or if there any white spaces on the right or left side of "=". For that, I can use trim(). The part I am struggling with is how to break the user input into 3 parts "name", "=" and "value" because later on, I want to sort the list by name and by value. Please, someone, point me in the right direction.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zl5r.png)

My code

```
$("#add-pair").on("submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const addItem = $('#add-pair > input[type="text"]').val();
if (!addItem || addItem === null) {
  $("#add-pair").append(
    '<div class="error">Cannot post empty string. Please add Name=Value!</div>'
  );
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".error").fadeOut();
  }, 4000);
} else {
  $li = $("<li>");
  $textSpan = $("<span>")
    .addClass("name")
    .text(addItem);
  $deleteSpan = $("<span>")
    .addClass("btn delete")
    .text("Delete");
  $listItem = $li.append($textSpan).append($deleteSpan);
  $("#list")
    .hide()
    .prepend($listItem)
    .fadeIn(500);
}
```

});

```
<form id="add-pair">
                <input type="text" name="addPair" id="input" placeholder="Name=Value..." />
                <button class="btn">Add</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: See the string function split https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Thankx man that's what I was looking for....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `split` to split along the string before the `=` and after the `=`:

```
const inputStr1 = ' name   = value  ';
const inputStr2 = ' name   value  ';
function validate(str) {
  if (!str.includes('=')) {
    console.log('no = found, returning');
    return;
  }
  const [cleanedName, cleanedValue] = str.split('=').map(uncleanStr => uncleanStr.trim());
  console.log('returning values "' + cleanedName + '" "' + cleanedValue + '"');
  return [cleanedName, cleanedValue];
}

const results1 = validate(inputStr1);
const results2 = validate(inputStr2);
```